# What is causing this error with my Active Record associations when I use model.collection.build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my project, I have the following three classes:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :portfolios, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :positions, through: :portfolios
end

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio
end
```

When I try to build a position directly off the user model (`user.positions.build(attributes)`) by passing in an existing portfolio_id as one of the attributes, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection (Cannot modify association 'User#positions' because the source reflection class 'Position' is associated to 'Portfolio' via :has_many.
```

Why would this happen? I feel there's something to be learned here but I don't really get it!

Addendum: I think my associations make sense: a portfolio should only belong to one user, a position to only one portfolio, and a portfolio should have multiple positions and a user multiple portfolios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build positions like this

```
user = User.first
portfolio_attributes = {name: 'Portfolio_1'}
position_attributes = {name: 'Postion_1'}
user.portfolios.build(portfolio_attributes).positions.build(position_attributes)
user.save!
```

When i run user.positions i get the below result

```
user.positions
  Position Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "positions".* FROM "positions" INNER JOIN "portfolios" ON "positions"."portfolio_id" = "portfolios"."id" WHERE "portfolios"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", nil], ["LIMIT", nil]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Position id: 1, name: "Postion_1", portfolio_id: 1>]>
```